# Effective wordcount multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, word-count

I am fairly new to C++ and multi-threading and need some help with creating a word count that effectively divides work between multiple threads.

Suppose, I have a function that counts words in a line (string):

```
count_words_in_line(line);
```

For one thread, the total words in line is the simple sum of this function output for each line, but how do I divide that into threads?

My idea was to use two threads - one to count even and one to count odd lines, but the code results in a Segmentation Fault.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?**

I would like to not use a threadpool, and would ideally like to specify the number of threads in an argument in order to measure the performance of the multithreaded implementation.

Here is my relevant code:

```
bool odd = true;
auto thread_count_odd = [&counter, &infile, &odd, &line, &mutex]() {
    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        if (odd) {
            std::cout<<"Count odd"<<std::endl;
            mutex.lock();
            counter += count_words_in_line(line);
            mutex.unlock();
        }
        odd = !odd;
    }
};

bool even = false;
auto thread_count_even = [&counter, &infile, &even, &line, &mutex]() {

    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        if (even) {
            std::cout<<"Count even"<<std::endl;
            mutex.lock();
            counter += count_words_in_line(line);
            mutex.unlock();
        }
        even = !even;
    }
};

std::thread t1(thread_count_odd);
std::thread t2(thread_count_even);

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Comment: You access concurrently `infile` (and line) without synchronization...

Comment: You also count_words_in_line() while your mutex is locked

Comment: Simpler would be to create a vector of lines, and then use thread to count word from the const vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you must have a mutex around getline call. Both threads are accessing infile at the same time which might be causing issues.

I have this code which would work for your situation using conditional variables. Hope this helps

`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<string>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#define MAX_THREADS 50
using namespace std;
thread *threads = new thread[MAX_THREADS];

condition_variable cv[MAX_THREADS];
mutex m1;
int counter=0;
int count_words_in_line(string line){
        /*write your code here*/
        return 1;
}

void printString(int tid, ifstream &inFile, int tcount)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
    while(1)
    {
        string line;
        inFile >> line;
        string a = "";
        if(line==a)break;
        cv[(tid+1)%tcount].notify_one();
        cv[tid].wait(lock);
        counter += count_words_in_line(line);
    }
    cv[(tid+1)%tcount].notify_one();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tcount, ccount, k;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    string name;
    inFile.open("input.txt");
    string str;
    tcount = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < tcount; i++) {
        threads[i] = thread(printString, i, ref(inFile), tcount);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tcount; i++)
        threads[i].join();

    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

- Use a shared vector with read-index/write-index and mutex/condition-variable (as suggested by Jarod42).
- Start the counting threads, waiting for write-index being greater than read index.
- Let the main thread read in the lines and fill the vector and notify the condition-variable accordingly.
- When the counting threads see that the write-index has increased, they can read the line and do the counting.
- The main thread indicates that the file is read completely.  The counting threads return the result which is passed by `join()`.  So the results can be added.

Remark: it is possible that only one thread will do the counting, which would indicate that other threads were not needed.  There are at least 2 threads: a reading thread and a processing thread.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Could you elaborate a bit more on the shared vector/provide a code snippet? i have never encountered it and am not sure how to catch/detect a change in the write-index, as you propose...

Answer (score 0):

If the thread only reads from file there is no need for mutex. You can have number of threads skip lines in txt file so that every thread has its own line to read, then merge the result. Works well for big files >1GB For example:

```
void readerThread(char *argv[], std::unordered_set<std::string>& uniqueWords, size_t threadIndex, size_t maxThreads)
{
    std::ifstream fin (argv[1]);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        for (size_t i = 1; i < threadIndex; i++)
        {
             fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        while (fin)
        {
           getline(fin, line);
           std::string word;
           std::stringstream ss (line);
           while (getline (ss, word, ' '))
           {
               uniqueWords.insert (word);
           }
           for (size_t i = 1; i < maxThreads; i++)
           {
                fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
           }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("file error");
    }
}
```

and in main:

```
    const auto processorCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<std::unordered_set<std::string>> vecOfSet;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> uniqueWords;
    unsigned int uniqueWordsCount = 0;

                for(size_t threads = 0; threads < processorCount; threads++)
                {
                    vecOfSet.emplace_back(std::unordered_set<std::string>());
                }
                std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
                for(size_t threads = 0; threads < processorCount; threads++)
                {
                    std::thread thread_([ &vecOfSet, threads, argv, processorCount]() { readerThread( argv, std::ref(vecOfSet.at(threads)), threads+1, processorCount);});
                    threads_.push_back(std::move(thread_));
                }

                for(size_t threads = 0; threads < processorCount; threads++)
                {
                    threads_.at(threads).join();
                }
                for(size_t threads = 0; threads < processorCount; threads++)
                {
                    uniqueWords.merge(vecOfSet.at(threads));
                }
                uniqueWordsCount = uniqueWords.size();
```